# phpmyadmin stopped woking (1045)

Tags: 12.04, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I was working on phpmyadmin normally, but today for some reason every time i try to login with any user "even the root user", i receive the below error

```
#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

I checked mysql is running normally on server, and i can login using command line with all users normally.

There is no error log in apache or mysql!

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary of multiple possible solutions**

Apparently one of the methods (comments) helped to solve the problem, so I summarize them here:

1. **Modify configuration file:**

   Edit `config.inc.php`:

   Change `localhost`to `127.0.0.1`.

   You can find the configuration file in `/etc/phpmyadmin/`.

   No restarting of phpMyAdmin is required since edits in this configuration file are applied automatically.
2. **Creating a new password:**

   ```
   $ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
   ```
3. **Reinstalling phpMyAdmin (Uninstallation + new Installation):**

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
   ```

   More Details for the new installation can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: modified in both lines: `if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = '127.0.0.1';` and `if (!empty($dbport) || $dbserver != '127.0.0.1')`, still same error!

Comment: `$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD` could also help

Comment: I tried to change the root password, flushed the privileges, and restarted mysql, same issue!

Comment: The weird thing is, i didn't change anything related to mysql lately, suddenly all users fails to login using phpmyadmin, but works perfectly on command line

Comment: So it probably has only to do with phpma, did you try a simple reinstallation of phpmyadmin or did you make many configuration changes?

Comment: nop i didn't :(, and for the mysqladmin the output was: `mysqladmin -u root password 12345678
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'`

Comment: I would try a reinstallation respectively removing+new installation.

Comment: reinstalling phpmyadmin shouldn't affect anything to php or mysql right?, also is there anyway to see phpmyadmin logs on the server?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: yes it doesn't affect php or mysql unless you have created code or files in the phpmyadmin folder.

Comment: So a reinstallation helped`?